# Trouble centering content in hero

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time trying to understand how to center this content within a hero. I want the content to be centered in the middle vertically, and horizontally. I would like the solution to be responsive.

Here is an example of what I am looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLZDT.png

Here is my html:

```
<div class="Hero">
<div class="Hero_Container">
<h2 class="hero_header">Chef Prepared Meals.</h2> 
<h2 class="hero_header">Home Cooked Taste</h2>
<h3>Delivered Warm To Your Door</h3>
<button class="browse_menu_btn" href="/menus/">Browse This Week's Menu <br> Order Online</button>
<br>
<a href="/delivery">Check Our Dallas Delivery Area</a>
</div>  
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
div.Hero {
background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0456/2857/t/2/assets/stock_bg.jpg?215 );
background-size: 100% auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 500px;
}

div.Hero_Container {
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Any help, or suggestions, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to center the div.Hero_Container, for an element 400px x 400px:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -200px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -200px;
```

Comment: I should have specified in the question, I would like for this to be a responsive option.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a way to have position: relative/responsive layout for vertical and horizontal centering, sorry... one way to center horizontal is so set margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto.  You could try something like that I guess